# How can i connect my pyqt login to a qstackedwidget new window in python

Tags: python, qt, authentication, dialog, pyqt4

Making a  program and ive made a login system to connect the user to the main menu. So far ive got it to work but not to what i like. My code launches the program well but im having trouble with the if **name** == '**main**': subroutine. My problem is very similar to [Login dialog PyQt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11812000/login-dialog-pyqt?rq=1)

Login excerpt

```
class Ui_Login(QtGui.QDialog):
def __init__(self):
    QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
    self.dbu = db.DatabaseUtility('UsernamePassword_DB', 'masterTable')
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.confirm = None
```

Mainwidget exceprt

```
class MainWidget(QWidget):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(MainWidget, self).__init__(parent)
    self.stack = QStackedWidget()
    layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
    layout.addWidget(self.stack)
    self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 250)
```

The problem arises when i get to the name section.
     if **name** == '**main**':

```
import sys
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

if Ui_Login().exec_() == QtGui.QDialog.Accepted:
    sys.exit()
    w = MainWidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit()
```

This If correct username and password are entered, then main window is shown. But, the login form stays active, and if I close it, the main window will also close. I also tried another method

```
if __name__ == '__main__':   
  app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
  ex = Ui_Login()
  ex.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  w = MainWidget()
  w.show()
  app.exec_()
  sys.exit()
```

This meant that i would login as normal and the main window would come up but however the buttons wasn't working as it was not connecting to the other form. So the main widget class wasn't working. i tried again

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ui_Login()
    w = MainWidget()
    ex.show()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    sys.exit()
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
```

So this meant both the login dialog and the main window would load at the same time. However the button would work on the mainwindow. However it was not connected to my login system.

So the question how can i connect both the login system and the mainwindow together. Hopefully this question wasn't long and unwieldy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned through looking at my code i put the show menu signal in the wrong place, which meant the main menu form would load without the password needing to be right. Poor testing on my behalf. However i still needed to alter the if **name** == '**main**': subroutine. i made the following adjustments.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':    
  app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
  if Ui_Login().exec_()==QtGui.QDialog.Accepted:
  w = MainWidget()
  w.show()
  sys.exit()
```

This solved my problem and the user log in connects to the main-menu properly and the stackedwidget works perfectly.