# PyQt4: Second window does not show

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

Here is the code *open.py* (main file) that opens a login page that has a button which when clicked closes the login page and opens a menu page:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys
from loginpage import Ui_loginPage
from menu import Ui_Menu

class Form1(QtGui.QWidget, Ui_loginPage):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.login.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        self.window2 = None

    def handleButton(self):
        self.close()
        if self.window2 is None:
            self.window2 = menu(self)
        self.window2.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())


class menu(QtGui.QWidget, Ui_Menu):     
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':       

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Form1()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The code runs fine without any error, but when i click the login button, the login page closes but the menu page doesn't appear. It just doesn't show at all.

Comment: `menu` doesn't take any arguments, why are you passing it `self`?

Comment: i did some changes and didnt pass self in menu.....still no luck

Answer (score 0):

If the `menu` window is a child of the `Form1` window, it will be hidden when the `Form1` window is closed - so don't give it a parent. You also shouldn't be calling `sys.exit(app.exec_())` again, so your code should look like this:

```
class Form1(QtGui.QWidget, Ui_loginPage):
    ...

    def handleButton(self):
        self.close()
        if self.window2 is None:
            self.window2 = menu()
        self.window2.show()
```

PS: please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11812578/984421) for a more complete example of how to implement a login dialog in PyQt.