# PyQt4 sharing QLineEdit variable across .py files

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I want to pass self.user = QtGui.QLineEdit(MainWindow) variable from Login.py to officer  = str(self.tocomb.currentText()) in ingooi.py

My 3 GUI windows

[image]

My program consists of various files where I import the classes from other files as needed.

The 3 main files consists of :

1. Login.py ( My Login window where user logs in )
2. page22.py ( User selects to enter/view data )
3. ingooi.py ( User enters data then adds the data to access database via Submit 
   Button

Please see the code for these 3 main files below.

## Login.py

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from ingooi import Ui_NextPage
from page22 import Ui_Page1
import pypyodbc


try:
_fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8  
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig,   
_encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Logged(object):

def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
    MainWindow.resize(389, 235)
    self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
    self.Login_button = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.Login_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 150, 75, 23))    
    self.Login_button.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Login_button"))


    self.user = QtGui.QLineEdit(MainWindow)


    self.user.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 30, 113, 20))
    self.user.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("user"))

    self.password = QtGui.QLineEdit(MainWindow)        
    self.password.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 70, 113, 20))
    self.password.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("password"))
    self.password.setEchoMode(QtGui.QLineEdit.Password)       
    self.user_label = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.user_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 46, 13))
    self.user_label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("user_label"))       
    self.Password_label = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.Password_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 70, 46, 13))
    self.Password_label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Password_label"))     
    self.status_label = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.status_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 110, 121, 16))   
    self.status_label.setText(_fromUtf8(""))    
    self.status_label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("status_label"))
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 389, 21))
    self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
    MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
    self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.Login_button,   QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.slot1)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Login ", None))
    self.Login_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Login ", None))
    self.user_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "User", None))
    self.Password_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Password", None))


def WW(self):

    self.window = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    self.ui = Ui_Page1()
    self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
    self.window.show()
    MainWindow.hide()


def slot1(self):

    uName = self.user.text()
    uPass = self.password.text()


    print uName
    print uPass


    conn = pypyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Driver do Microsoft Access     (*.mdb)};UID=admin;UserCommitSync=Yes;Threads=3;SafeTransactions=0;PageTimeout=5 
 ;MaxScanRows=8;MaxBufferSize=2048;FIL={MS     Access};DriverId=25;DefaultDir=//ICASACTNFS02/Share/New;DBQ=//ICASACTNFS02/Share/  New/snake.mdb')  


    cursor = conn.cursor()

    sql = "SELECT * FROM gtable WHERE User = '%s' AND pwd = '%s'"% 
 (uName,uPass)

    see = cursor.execute(sql)

    if (len (see.fetchall()) > 0) :

        print " User OK !"


        self.WW()

        conn.close()

    else:


        self.status_label.setText(_fromUtf8("Try ma wee"))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_Logged()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

## Page22.py

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui  
from ingooi import Ui_NextPage  
from tafel import Ui_Main  
from tafel2 import Ui_TaPage  
import pypyodbc  
import sys  

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig,   _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Page1(object):


def setupUi(self, Page1):
    Page1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Page1"))
    Page1.resize(586, 617)
    self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(Page1)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
    self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 40, 300, 61))
    self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))

    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.dataenter)

    self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 130, 291, 61))
    self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_2"))

    self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.dataview)

    self.pushButton_3 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 220, 291, 61))
    self.pushButton_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_3"))

    self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.Taview)

    self.pushButton_4 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 310, 291, 61))
    self.pushButton_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_4"))


    self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.exit)

    Page1.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(Page1)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 586, 21))
    self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
    Page1.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
    self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(Page1)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
    Page1.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

    self.retranslateUi(Page1)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Page1)

def retranslateUi(self, Page1):
    Page1.setWindowTitle(_translate("Page1", "MainWindow", None))
    self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Page1", "Data Entry ", None))
    self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Page1", "View Data ", None))

    self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Page1", " Type Approved Device   
List    ", None))

    self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("Page1", "EXIT ", None))

def dataenter(self):

    self.window = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    self.ui = Ui_NextPage()
    self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
    self.window.show()        

def dataview(self):

    self.window = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    self.ui = Ui_Main()
    self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
    self.window.show()

def Taview(self):

    self.window = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    self.ui = Ui_TaPage()
    self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
    self.window.show()


def exit(self):


    sys.exit()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Page1 = QtGui.QMainWindow()

    ui = Ui_Page1()
    ui.setupUi(Page1)
    Page1.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

## ingooi.py

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import pypyodbc
from tafel import Ui_Main
import subprocess
import sys

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
 except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig,   _encoding)  
except AttributeError:
def _translate(context, text, disambig):
    return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_NextPage(object):


def ViewPage(self):


    self.window = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    self.ui = Ui_Main()
    self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
    self.window.show()

def load(self):

    mydate = self.insp_date_comb.date()

    realdate = mydate.toString("dd/MM/yyyy")

    lic_name = str(self.lic_name_comb.currentText())
    lic_num = str(self.lic_nr_comb.currentText())
    systm = str(self.sys_name_comb.currentText())
    Loc = str(self.Loc_comb.currentText())

    txfreq = str(self.tx_comb.currentText())
    rxfreq = str(self.rx_comb.currentText())
    fwdpwr = str(self.fwdpwr_comb.currentText())  
    rflpwr = str(self.rflpwr_comb.currentText())

    officer  = str(self.tocomb.currentText()) 

    print lic_name
    print realdate


    conn = pypyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Driver do Microsoft Access   (*.mdb)};UID=admin;UserCommitSync=Yes;Threads=3;SafeTransactions=0;PageTimeout=5
;MaxScanRows=8;MaxBufferSize=2048;FIL={MS   Access};DriverId=25;DefaultDir=//ICASACTNFS02/Share/New;DBQ=//ICASACTNFS02/Share   /New/snake.mdb')
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    # query = "DELETE FROM measdata WHERE RFL_PWR = '%s'" %(0) 

    query = "INSERT INTO measdata     (Licensee,Lic_number,System,Location,Insp_date,TX,RX,FWD_PWR,RFL_PWR,TO) VALUES     ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')" %   (lic_name,lic_num,systm,Loc,realdate,txfreq,rxfreq,fwdpwr,rflpwr,officer) 

    cursor.execute(query)

    conn.commit()

    conn.close()


def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
    MainWindow.resize(544, 516)
    self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
    self.lic_name_comb = QtGui.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
    self.lic_name_comb.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 20, 181, 22))
    self.lic_name_comb.setEditable(True)
    self.lic_name_comb.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lic_name_comb"))
    self.lic_name_comb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.lic_name_comb.setItemText(0, _fromUtf8(""))
    self.lic_name_comb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.lic_name_comb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.lic_name_comb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))

    self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 81, 31))
    self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))

    self.tolabel = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.tolabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 350, 70, 23))
    self.tolabel.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tolabel"))

    self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 50, 71, 21))
    self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
    self.lic_nr_comb = QtGui.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
    self.lic_nr_comb.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 50, 101, 22))
    self.lic_nr_comb.setEditable(True)
    self.lic_nr_comb.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lic_nr_comb"))
    self.lic_nr_comb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.lic_nr_comb.setItemText(0, _fromUtf8(""))
    self.lic_nr_comb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.lic_nr_comb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.lic_nr_comb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.label_8 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 80, 71, 21))
    self.label_8.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_8"))
    self.sys_name_comb = QtGui.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
    self.sys_name_comb.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 80, 101, 22))
    self.sys_name_comb.setEditable(True)
    self.sys_name_comb.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("sys_name_comb"))
    self.sys_name_comb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.sys_name_comb.setItemText(0, _fromUtf8(""))

    self.sys_name_comb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.sys_name_comb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.sys_name_comb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.sys_name_comb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.sys_name_comb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.sys_name_comb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))

    self.insp_date_comb = QtGui.QDateEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.insp_date_comb.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 150, 110, 22))
    self.insp_date_comb.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("insp_date_comb"))

    self.insp_date_comb.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime())

    self.insp_date_comb.setCalendarPopup(True)

    self.label_9 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 150, 81, 16))
    self.label_9.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_9"))

    self.submit_btn = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.submit_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 415, 70, 23))
    self.submit_btn.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("submit_btn"))

    self.submit_btn.clicked.connect(self.load)

    self.Loc_comb = QtGui.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
    self.Loc_comb.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 110, 101, 22))
    self.Loc_comb.setEditable(True)
    self.Loc_comb.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Loc_comb"))
    self.Loc_comb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.Loc_comb.setItemText(0, _fromUtf8(""))
    self.Loc_comb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.Loc_comb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.label_10 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 110, 71, 21))
    self.label_10.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_10"))

    self.rx_comb = QtGui.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
    self.rx_comb.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 220, 69, 22))
    self.rx_comb.setEditable(True)
    self.rx_comb.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("rx_comb"))
    self.rx_comb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.rx_comb.setItemText(0, _fromUtf8(""))
    self.rx_comb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.rx_comb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.rx_comb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.rx_comb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.rx_comb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))

    self.tocomb = QtGui.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
    self.tocomb.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 348, 110, 22))
    self.tocomb.setEditable(True)
    self.tocomb.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("rx_comb"))
    self.tocomb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.tocomb.setItemText(0, _fromUtf8(""))
    self.tocomb.addItem(_fromUtf8("VAN NIEKERK B.A"))
    self.tocomb.addItem(_fromUtf8("ERASMUS C.M"))
    self.tocomb.addItem(_fromUtf8("FRANSMAN G.F"))
    self.tocomb.addItem(_fromUtf8("COOK H.A"))
    self.tocomb.addItem(_fromUtf8("MCQUIRE L."))
    self.tocomb.addItem(_fromUtf8("Gertse RS"))

    self.label_6 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 220, 71, 21))
    self.label_6.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_6"))
    self.fwdpwr_comb = QtGui.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
    self.fwdpwr_comb.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 280, 69, 22))
    self.fwdpwr_comb.setEditable(True)
    self.fwdpwr_comb.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("fwdpwr_comb"))
    self.fwdpwr_comb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.fwdpwr_comb.setItemText(0, _fromUtf8(""))
    self.fwdpwr_comb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.fwdpwr_comb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.fwdpwr_comb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.rflpwr_comb = QtGui.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
    self.rflpwr_comb.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 310, 69, 22))
    self.rflpwr_comb.setEditable(True)
    self.rflpwr_comb.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("rflpwr_comb"))
    self.rflpwr_comb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.rflpwr_comb.setItemText(0, _fromUtf8(""))
    self.rflpwr_comb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.rflpwr_comb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.rflpwr_comb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.rflpwr_comb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.rflpwr_comb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.label_4 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 310, 71, 21))
    self.label_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_4"))
    self.label_5 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 190, 71, 21))
    self.label_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_5"))
    self.label_3 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 280, 71, 21))
    self.label_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_3"))
    self.tx_comb = QtGui.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
    self.tx_comb.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 190, 69, 22))
    self.tx_comb.setEditable(True)
    self.tx_comb.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tx_comb"))
    self.tx_comb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.tx_comb.setItemText(0, _fromUtf8(""))
    self.tx_comb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.tx_comb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.tx_comb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.tx_comb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.tx_comb.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))

    self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 450, 90, 23))
    self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))

    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 544, 21))
    self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
    MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
    self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
    self.lic_name_comb.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Comms 1 ",   None))
    self.lic_name_comb.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Comms 2",   None))
    self.lic_name_comb.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "Comms 3",   None))
    self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Licensee", None))
    self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "License nr", None))
    self.lic_nr_comb.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "12345689",   None))
    self.lic_nr_comb.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "13634568",   None))
    self.lic_nr_comb.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "56345689",   None))
    self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "System", None))

    self.sys_name_comb.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Repeater ",   None))
    self.sys_name_comb.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Telemetry", None))
    self.sys_name_comb.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "Trunking ",   None))
    self.sys_name_comb.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "Alarm",   None))
    self.sys_name_comb.setItemText(5, _translate("MainWindow", "Relay",   None))

    self.insp_date_comb.setDisplayFormat(_translate("MainWindow",   "d/M/yyyy", None))
    self.label_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Inspection Date", None))
    self.submit_btn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Submit", None))
    self.Loc_comb.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Location 1 ",   None))
    self.Loc_comb.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Location 2 ",   None))

    self.label_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Location", None))

    self.tolabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "OFFICER", None))

    self.rx_comb.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "100", None))
    self.rx_comb.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "200", None))
    self.rx_comb.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "300", None))
    self.rx_comb.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "400", None))
    self.rx_comb.setItemText(5, _translate("MainWindow", "500", None))
    self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "RX FREQ", None))
    self.fwdpwr_comb.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "10", None))
    self.fwdpwr_comb.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "20", None))
    self.fwdpwr_comb.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "30", None))
    self.rflpwr_comb.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "1", None))
    self.rflpwr_comb.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "2", None))
    self.rflpwr_comb.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "3", None))
    self.rflpwr_comb.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "4", None))
    self.rflpwr_comb.setItemText(5, _translate("MainWindow", "5", None))
    self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "REFL PWR", None))
    self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TX FREQ", None))
    self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "FWD PWR ", None))
    self.tx_comb.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "100", None))
    self.tx_comb.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "200", None))
    self.tx_comb.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "300", None))
    self.tx_comb.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "400", None))
    self.tx_comb.setItemText(5, _translate("MainWindow", "500", None))

    self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "View Data ", None))

    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.ViewPage)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_NextPage()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: To what question do you mean that I responded?

Comment: If you want us to help you, you must provide a [mcve], also read [ask]

Comment: @eyllanesc i Have edited my question

Comment: According to what I see your question goes in another direction, in the case of the previous question he just wanted to call a generic script, but that is not appropriate if the other script is part of your GUI, it will be unbeatable in the long term. I proposed that solution because the other script was used once and no further interaction was needed. It is a very particular case. I could help you if you provide a complete code of what you want, I only see incomplete scraps of your code.

Comment: Why are you using two scripts? Put all the code in one script, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11812578/984421).

Comment: @eyllanesc I have added complete code and image of windows where variable should be taken accross . Hope this helps

Comment: @user3890023 Do you want to pass the contents of self.user to the variable officer or set it in the QComboBox tocomb?

Besides, at what moment do you want to pass it?

Comment: @eyllanesc I want to pass content of self.user to be set in QComboBox tocomb yes . ( I will eventually change that QComboBox to a QLineEdit ) . I want to pass it on once user press Login from Login window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your design, you should not think that each file is a different program, it is really only one.

Another recommendation is that you do not modify the code generated by QtDesigner, this is not necessary also if you want to modify something in the GUI will erase all the above, for example if you have a design for example the Login.py:

```
class Ui_Logged(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
      [...]
```

Then you must create another class that implements the logic

```
class Login(QtGui.QMainWindow, Login.Ui_Logged):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
        [...]
```

then in your case you have to `Page1()` member of the class and show it when you call `WW()`, you should not create it just open it

```
class Login(QtGui.QMainWindow, Login.Ui_Logged):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.Login_button.clicked(self.slot1)
        self.window = Page1()

    def WW(self):
        self.window.show()
        self.hide()
```

The same thing you have to do in `Page1()` with each slot. `NextPage()` is the class that implements the logic of `Ui_NextPage()`

```
class Page1(QtGui.QMainWindow, Page22.Ui_Page1)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.dataenter)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.dataview)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.Taview)
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.exit)
        self.nextPage = NextPage()

    def dataenter(self):
        self.nextPage.show()  

        [...]
```

So if we have that logic it's easy to call to access the QComboBox from `slot()`:

```
def slot1(self):
    uName = self.user.text()
    uPass = self.password.text()
    combo = self.window.nextPage.tocomb
    items = [combo.itemText(i) for i in range(combo.count())]
    if uName not in items:
        combo.addItem(uName)
    combo.setCurrentTex(uName)
```

I have tried to order your code, maybe have import problems but I think they should be minimal so you can fix them, run the file main.py. The complete code can be found at the following [link](https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/c5b7516b2ffd5274f50e1af996e9d03c).

Comment: Worked . Thank you !!