# QLineEdit outputs an empty string?

Tags: python, pyside

**UPDATE** I made a function to get the text from `QLineEdit` in the `logingui` file, and it works. I have no idea why the same function wouldn't work if imported from a different file.

I am trying to get text from `QLineEdit` on a button click, I have 2 files, `logingui` and `loginlogic`. Both the files import each other. Here's the `logingui`'s code

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import login.loginlogic

class LoginForm(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent=None)

        object = login.loginlogic


        formLayout = QFormLayout()
        # vboxlayout = QVBoxLayout()

        serifFont = QFont("Arial", 10)

        unamelbl = QLabel("Username")
        unamelbl.setFont(serifFont)
        pwdlbl = QLabel("Password")
        pwdlbl.setFont(serifFont)

        self.unamele = QLineEdit()
        self.pwdle = QLineEdit()

        self.unamele.setPlaceholderText("Username")
        self.pwdle.setPlaceholderText("Password")

        self.loginButton = QPushButton("Login")

        self.loginButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: #99ff99; font-size: 15px;")
        self.loginButton.setFont(serifFont)
        self.loginButton.clicked.connect(object.handleLogin)

        formLayout.addRow(unamelbl)
        formLayout.addRow(self.unamele)
        formLayout.addRow(pwdlbl)
        formLayout.addRow(self.pwdle)
        formLayout.addRow(self.loginButton)

        formLayout.setSpacing(20)

        self.setLayout(formLayout)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255,255,255)")
        self.setMinimumSize(420, 320)
        self.setMaximumSize(420, 320)
        self.setContentsMargins(60, 50, 60, 50)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("favicon.ico"))
        self.show()

    def handlelogin(self):
        u = self.unamele.text()
        print(u)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = LoginForm()
    app.exec_()
```

here's the code from `loginlogic`

```
import login.logingui


class handleLogin():
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj = login.logingui.LoginForm()
        self.username = self.obj.unamele.text()
        print("the code did reach here my man ")
        print(self.username)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = handleLogin()
```

now the output that I get is

`your code reached here`
`*blank line*`

I know that's a blank line cause when I click the button again it just leaves an empty line and the reached here text again. Also when I run the `logingui`, I do write some text in it. Not leaving it blank.

Comment: Use `exec_()` instead of `show()`.

Comment: I updated the question, please take a look at it @ekhumoro

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: added the full code @ekhumoro

Comment: Your code makes no sense at all. Please explain in detail what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @ekhumoro I am trying to access the text from QLineEdit of one class from another. That's all I am trying to do. And your comment hurt man.

Comment: I politely asked you to explain what you are trying to achieve, because I cannot I guess it from your code. If you want to know how to write a login dialog, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11812578/984421). If that isn't what you want, you will have to explain more clearly.

Comment: I know, I was just kidding @ekhumoro